# Calling Azurefunction from a logic app throws "Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support this configuration."

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a logic app, this calls several functionapps.
this worked wonderfull, but suddently I got an error when the logic app calls the Function. The error was:

```
{
  "Message": "The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value."
}
```

We didn't regenerate the key and the keys are valid, because we can execute the webhook functions with postman.

But when I isnpect the activity logs I got on the listkeys action the following Error:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support this configuration.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetKeyObjectFromFile>d__9`1.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetFunctionSecretsAsync>d__12.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at Kudu.Services.Functions.FunctionController.<GetSecrets>d__12.MoveNext()"
}
```

Is there a way to change the storage of the keys? Why I got suddently without any change this message from one minute to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my Problem.

It figured out that a Appsetting was the error indicator for this.

When you set the Appsetting "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType" to "blob" then you will get the error above!

Removing this setting solved this problem for me!

Comment: This likely got set when you enabled slots. Note that slots won't work correctly without this. Bottom line is that slots don't play well with Logic Apps. In fact, portal makes that explicit: "*Logic apps integration with Functions does not work when Slots(preview) is enabled.
Opting into this preview feature will reset any pre-existing secrets. Function secrets can be found under the 'Manage' node for each function.*"