# Azure Logic App: Create CSV File in Blob

Tags: azure, csv, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am having a problem updating a csv file in my blob. I have an existing file inside my blob which is a CSV file, and when I press the download button it will automatically download the file to my machine.

Now I already created a Logic App that will update the csv file. When I run the trigger of the app, it updates the file but when I press download, it opens up a new tab where the csv file will be displayed.

I want it the way like the original when I press download it download the file to my machine.

Any help will do or verification if this is possible.

I already tried "compose" and "create to csv" but this way it will not store it to a blob.

Comment: Are you using the `get blob content` action ? If you click on `show advanced options` you will see a `Infer Content Type` field. Set it to `No`  and it should work.

Comment: Because you content-type is text/plain, you need to set it as application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have test, when you want to create a .csv file with "**create blob**" action in logic app, it will always get the same problem with you. Because the blob content is "`text/plan`" which will display in another tab to show.

So, I suggest that you could use azure function to create the blob. In azure function you could set:`blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"`;

Here is the create blob method in azure function:

```
    storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

    client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    container = client.GetContainerReference("data");

    await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
    blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
    {
        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }
```

For more detailed code, you could refer to this [article](https://www.cyotek.com/blog/upload-data-to-blob-storage-with-azure-functions). After following  that, you could download your blob in your local machine.

**Note**: when you create the azure function action in logic app, it will [show error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987439/calling-azurefunction-from-a-logic-app-throws-runtime-keys-are-stored-on-blob-s). Just **delete Appsetting of "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType" to "blob"**.

Comment: thanks. Took me a few days to understand but I got it. :)